# Can you sort/order a PHP FOR loop?

Tags: php, sorting, loops, for-loop

Trying to get this awful joomla addon component to work the way the client is asking it to. And I have this for loop in there that loads the results in a bit of a random way. So I'm trying to get it to at least sort in at least 1 specific order. And I believe it needs to be done within the FOR loop.

Here is how the loop is setup:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($vehicle_feature); $i++) {
```

I would like to order it by $fk_featureid. Is it possible within a FOR loop? What would the syntax be?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is how the array is setup, first each item needs to be grouped together under their category, then I'd like it to sort each item alphabetically under their category:

```
Array   (   
        [0] => StdClass Object  (
            [Id] => 138 
            [Name] => Controls 
            [Categories] => Augers & Hydraulics 
            [Published] => 1 
            [Image_link] =>     )

        [1] => StdClass Object  (
            [Id] => 122 
            [Name] => Auger Drives 
            [Categories] => Augers & Hydraulics 
            [Published] => 1 
            [Image_link] =>     )
    )
```

Comment: how about sorting before the loop? http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: If the set of values is in the form of an array. You have specific function for it. http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Can you provide more info about the structure of $vehicle_feature? Like the output of a print_r or var_dump?

Comment: a couple of variables it will contain is ID and NAME. I think ordering by name would work well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, but it wasn't by trying to reorder the array that joomla was creating.

I found the query string that was pulling all of the featured items. In the ORDER BY attributes it was already sorting by category, which is good. But I needed it to order all of the items underneath each category as well. I solved this by simply adding a comma and "name" to the ORDER BY attribute. (ORDER BY category, name).

That did the trick. Thanks for all your feedback every one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort in a `for` loop, because that's not what they're for.  You can sort in advance, though.

```
array_sort($vehicle_feature);
for($i = 0; $i < count($vehicle_feature); $i++) { ...
```

See [array_sort](https://www.php.net/array_sort).

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do. First sort it out and then do loops!